# Comparing two text files and counting the differences

Tags: python

I have been trying to compare two text files in Python, essentially I want to open them and compare a single character at a time if the characters are different add 1 to a counter and then display this value.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

diff = 0

import random
import string
import sys

file_A = sys.argv[1]
file_B = sys.argv[2]

read_A=open(file_A,'r').read()
read_B=open(file_B,'r').read()

for a in read_A:
    for b in read_B:
        if a != b:
            diff = diff + 1
    return diff
break

print "No of Differences ",diff
```

Right now it does count but the value it returns does not seem correct.

Comment: Are both of your files the same size? If not, how would you want your script to handle that?

Comment: It looks to me like you are just starting your journey in Python and maybe programming.  I Googled for comparing two text files and came up with 335K results.  I would encourage you to look at those examples.  Your question is too vague.  If you really want an answer you should illustrate why the output you are getting is not what you expected.  But really you should close this question and go look at one of the solutions and try to understand it.

Comment: Do you want to compare line by line ?

Comment: No it would be a comparison character by character

Comment: you got some thing like this `NameError: name 'diff' is not defined`.check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two strings which you want to compare character by character, it seems best to zip them.

So, once you've doe this:

```
read_A=open(file_A,'r').read()
read_B=open(file_B,'r').read()
```

you do:

```
for char_a, char_b in zip(read_A, read_B):
    if char_a != char_b:
        # something
```

If your files are very big, you may wish to only read character by character and use `izip` instead of `zip`...

**BTW...**

You are not closing your files. It is a good idea to always access files this way:

```
with open(file_A, 'r') as f1:
    read_A = f1.read()

with open(file_B, 'r') as f2:
    read_B = f2.read()
```

Comment: If the files are very big, he's better off reading one byte from both files at a time and compare them. You can break the loop either when one file returns the EOF literal, or even better, iterate as many times as the smaller file's byte count. `zip()` behaves the same way for iterables anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this is to use [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html). It doesn't require any additional eggs for python and gives really good results for tracking various kinds of diff checks. The result of a diff check would be what you'd look toward to check for equality as well as close matches. That can be important as well if you allow for weighting of results.

Answer (score 1):

Looping isn't certainly the pythonic way to do it. Without using any external library, you can use simple list comprehension to find the instances of differences between two files:

If the order is significant:

```
x=[i for i, j in zip(read_A, read_B) if i != j]
print len(x)
```

If the order is *not* significant:

```
x=[i in read_B for i in read_A]
#Now count the instances where the comparison resulted in False
i = x.count(False)
```

Comment: This will chek whether any character in B matches a character in A, e.g. no difference for `read_B='abcdefgh'` and `read_A='aaabbc'`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I have edited my code for when the order is significant.