# Compare two files and return the first difference encountered

Tags: python

I wanted to know how I can find the first difference between 2 python Files ?

The script is a simple function that accept two arguments, these arguments are 'Files' and we compare these two Files, character to character and it's supposed to stop to the first difference between these two.

Here is what I've tried so far :

```
import sys 

def myDoubleFileFunction(param4, param5):

fics = open(param4, 'r')
focs = open(param5, 'r')

if fics.readlines() == focs.readlines():
    print('it\'s ok')
else:
    print('error')
```

myDoubleFileFunction('File', 'File1')
print(sys.argv)
It will display False because the files are not the same but I want it to stop at the first difference encountered.

Then I tried the thing with "diff" but it doesn't return the "first" difference.

Thanks

Edit : Okay so I tried with [Comparing two text files and counting the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252041/comparing-two-text-files-in-python-and-counting-the-differences#comment56246665_34252156) but it still didn't work

So I tried with zip too

```
def myDoubleFileFunction(param4, param5):

fics = open(param4, 'r').readlines()
focs = open(param5, 'r').readlines()
for char_a, char_b in zip(fics, focs):
    if char_a != char_b:
        print('this is false')
      
      


myDoubleFileFunction('File', 'File1')
```

What should I use ?

And when "this is false" is returned it should display the first difference encountered

A method in Difflib module ? If it's a method which one will give me the first difference and then stop the program ? Only the first difference ?

Comment: open both files, read in character after character, compare, break from comparing if difference found. What is your problem? Dont give multiple codes. Read about `break` to leave a loop. You are also using readlines() wich splits the files. Use read() to capture the file in full and compare character for character.

Comment: Can you please stop duplicating your questions? Ask one single question and edit it if more details are necessary

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that will give you the first difference in the files.

```
x = open("filepath", "r").read()
y = open("filepath", "r").read()

if len(x) < len(y):
  for index, item in enumerate(x):
    if item != y[index]:
      print(f"{item} != {y[index]}, difference at character {index}, file x is shorter than file y")
      break
elif len(x) > len(y):
  for index, item in enumerate(y):
    if item != x[index]:
      print(f"{item} != {y[index]}, difference at character {index}, file x is shorter than file y")
      break
else:
  for index, item in enumerate(y):
    if item != x[index]:
      print(f"{item} != {y[index]}, difference at character {index}, file x is shorter than file y")
      break
```

Comment: this seems overly complicated (maybe), also use `for item in iterable` not `for index in range(len(iterable))`

Comment: see [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function, that is what you should be using if you also need the index: `for index, item in enumerate(iterable):`